# How can I install wireless adapter driver for Digisol DG-WN3150Nu in ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, wireless, drivers

I am using HP Pavilion 15-n011TU and I have problems with wireless LAN driver. Unfortunately as per this [link](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1220146) there is no Ubuntu driver for the device. So I have purchased a USB wifi dongle (Digisol DG-WN3150Nu). By default it doesn't detect in Ubuntu 12.04. Any idea about how to install the driver? and enable it using `modprobe`.

`lsusb` returned:

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0461:4e22 Primax Electronics, Ltd 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 05c8:0361 Cheng Uei Precision Industry Co., Ltd (Foxlink) 
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 0bda:8176 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8188CUS 802.11n WLAN
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0e8d:763e MediaTek Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
```

I need to disable MediaTek adapter by default and load Digisol DG-WN3150Nu while booting, Thanks.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of this terminal command: `lsusb`.

Comment: I have edited the question to include those.

Answer (score 2):

Your USB wireless device works with the driver *rtl8192cu* in newer Ubuntu versions. Check to see if the driver in 12.04 covers your device:

```
sudo modprobe rtl8192cu
```

Does your wireless work now? Check the driver modalias:

```
modinfo rtl8192cu | grep 8176
```

If the installed driver does not cover your device, install a newer driver version. With a temporary working internet connection by ethernet, tethered or whatever means possible:

```
sudo apt-get install git linux-headers-generic build-essential dkms
git clone https://github.com/pvaret/rtl8192cu-fixes.git
sudo dkms add ./rtl8192cu-fixes
sudo dkms install 8192cu/1.10
sudo depmod -a
sudo cp ./rtl8192cu-fixes/blacklist-native-rtl8192.conf /etc/modprobe.d/
```

Reboot and tell us if it's working.