# How to install wireless adapter driver for Digisol DG-WN3150Nu B1 in ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, networking, drivers, wireless

I have bought a USB wifi dongle (Digisol DG-WN3150Nu B1). By default it doesn't detect in Ubuntu 12.04. Help needed in auto detection of wireless networks.

I have followed the steps [mentioned here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/651735/how-can-i-install-wireless-adapter-driver-for-digisol-dg-wn3150nu-in-ubuntu-12-0) that describes a similar problem. But doesn't seem to work for me.

Below are the output of the commands on my system

```
imprika@imprikalabs:~$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c534 Logitech, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04d9:1702 Holtek Semiconductor, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 148f:7601 Ralink Technology, Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
```

and

```
imprika@imprikalabs:~$ sudo modprobe rtl8192cu
WARNING: Error running install command for rtlwifi
WARNING: Error inserting rtl8192c_common (/lib/modules/3.13.0-92-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtl8192c/rtl8192c-common.ko): Unknown symbol in module, or unknown parameter (see dmesg)
FATAL: Error inserting rtl8192cu (/lib/modules/3.13.0-92-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtl8192cu/rtl8192cu.ko): Unknown symbol in module, or unknown parameter (see dmesg)
```

and

```
imprika@imprikalabs:~$ modinfo rtl8192cu | grep 8176
alias:          usb:v0BDAp8176d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Support for Ubuntu 12.04 will be discontinued on April 28, 2017.  I would recommend upgrading now, it might also solve your problem.

Comment: The correct driver for your device is mt7601u and not rtl8192cu. As well, your device is supported fully in later Ubuntu versions, especially 16.10.  I suggest you upgrade.

Comment: Please check here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/457061/ralink-mt7601u-148f7601-wi-fi-adapter-installation